# Distinguish SDCard URI from USBStorage URI returned by SAF or StorageVolume API

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage, usb-otg, storage-access-framework

I am using `StorageVolume` API to retrieve URI for both `SDCard` and `USBStorage` by following

```
StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
for (StorageVolume storageVolume : storageManager.getStorageVolumes())
    {
    if (!storageVolume.isPrimary())
       {
       Intent accessIntent = storageVolume.createAccessIntent(null);
       startActivityForResult(accessIntent, 11);
       }
     }
```

In `onActivityResult` I am able to retrieve the URI, saving it to the `SharedPreferences` and taking `Persisting Permission`. The thing is I am not able to distinguish the `SDCard`'s URI from `USBStorage`'s URI. It also applies for the URI's which are returned from `Storage Access Framework`. How could I really know that the user has really selected the expected storage not the wrong one.

**Things Tried**

1. I tried to send some data with the `createAccessIntent` but wasn't
   able to retrieve values in `onActivityResult`. Just wanted to know
   that why it doesn't have the extras that I put to the `Intent` returned by `createAccessIntent`.
2. I tried to `context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)[]` but it returns `null` for the `SDCard` item. I also checked the state of `SDCard` which was mounted. Obviously, I took runtime permission for storage from user.
3. Tried to assume that `storageManager.getStorageVolumes()` would return list of all the external storage with order of `USBStorage` at the first place as it does on my device but doesn't on all devices. It lists items randomly.
4. I also tried to use hack something like `Environment.getRootDirectory()` and get its parent and navigate to the `SDCard` on the root folder but it only returns the child elements of the mount point of `SDCard` and `USBStorage` on `Marshmellow` not beyond that. I mean it simply returns null on `Nougat`+ devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like the API was specifically designed to prevent whatever you are trying to do. Btw, why are you asking specifically for SD card vs USB storage? What if user tries to choose an internal hard drive (e.g. on Chromebook)? Dropbox? Goodle Drive folder? Maybe you shouln't try to distinguish precise storage types and instead check for specific properties, that you care about?

Comment: @user1643723 Well I don't think so. I mean, I can't even show user what they have selected? I mean they could have made mistake selecting the desired thing and want to change.

Comment: @user1643723 the reason I'm trying to do this is so that if a user has both an SD card and a USB drive connected I can provide understandable names to the "where do you want to store your data" UI.  In cases where they've only got a single removable storage options "Internal" and "Removable" would work.  If they've got both connected for some reason "Removable 1" and "Removable 2" give no indication of which is which.

Comment: A StorageVolume instance has a lot of properties. Also a name/description/info property. They can be used to let the user choose. But if you want the drive then it id always the last one. You can save that data and use in onActivityResult.

Comment: @blackapps To clarify, are you saying that a USB drive will always be the last drive listed? I guess because the volumes are shown in order of insertion?

Comment: No. Depends on actual device. Mostly after removable micro sd card and sometimes before. Never as first.

Comment: @blackapps So is your recommendation to just let the user choose which is the correct volume? Because the app I'm working on is meant to work for USB drives only.

Comment: Untested: getExternalFilesDirs() delivers micro sd card id like for instance FD19-123A. And now adays no usb drive anymore. You can check if you see that id as storage volume. If so then take the other.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a method that seems to work for this. It reads the `proc/mounts` file line-by-line until it finds one that contains both the provided `StorageVolume`'s UUID and the string `/dev/block/vold/public:179`. In my testing, it seems that `/dev/block/vold/public:179` indicates an SD card, whereas `/dev/block/vold/public:8` indicates a USB drive.

I know nothing about Linux, so I'd be curious if anyone could confirm or deny the veracity of this. But it works across all 6 of my devices that have SD card slots.

https://gist.github.com/gavingt/2eb239d5df4e56290c1c65f25b8db8bf

As for getting the UUID from a Uri, that part is trivial.