# Android: Determine what is SD card and what is USB disk

Tags: android, android-sdcard, sd-card, android-external-storage, usb-drive

In an Android app, I am storing files on a SD card in the device.

Occasionally the user also need to export data to a USB disk that will be attached for the occasion.

I am using `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()` to locate the SD card and I am using `Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()` to distinguish the internal storage from the SD card.

My problem is that the USB disk, when attached, show up the exact same way as the SD card. It is included in the list returned by `Context.getExternalFilesDirs()` and is also "removable" according to `Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()` and the path does not reveal anything.

Is there a way to distinguish an attached SD card from an attached USB drive?

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/53845539/833197